# GridLayout multiple grid sizes

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, android-recyclerview

Hi I'm trying to make a activity where the size of each grid it 1*1 and occasionally an 2*2 grid appears.
Here's What I'm trying to achieve:[image: This is somewhat I what to achieve]

I am using recycler view to populate my layout.
here is my staggered grid `StaggeredGridLayoutManager staggeredGridLayoutManager=new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(3, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);`

 I tried using different layouts but I didn't get what I wanted.thanks in advance.

Comment: It seams that your items have the same size. You can use the GridLayoutManager.

Answer (score 1):

If you all items have the same size (as a grid) you can use a [`GridLayoutManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/GridLayoutManager.html) and you can use the method  [`setSpanSizeLookup(SpanSizeLookup)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/GridLayoutManager.html#setSpanSizeLookup(androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup)) to change the default span (=1).

Something like:

```
layoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
            @Override
            public int getSpanSize(int position) {
                return // your implementation ...... ;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `FlexboxLayoutMananger`

Here you can find the usage:
https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout/blob/master/README.md#flexboxlayoutmanager-within-recyclerview